# What is the difference between an "if" and a "#if" in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and don't do a lot of object oriented programming. I have seen some examples that utilize #IF syntax for C#, but I don't know what it is doing differently than a regular IF.

Comment: `#` commands are compiler directives - they are evaluated at compile-time by the compiler, so they affect which code is actually compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This directive is usually used to add conditional code in compile-time. So, if you're compiling in Debug mode and you add something like

```
#if DEBUG 
 // something else
#endif
```

this part of the code will be compiled in Debug but skiped in Release

You can find more info here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: Ok, so it is a way to avoid compiling code that isn't needed in a given scenario.

Comment: @Jaked: That was the original intention when it was added back in C days: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor_directives_and_macros They still workl that way, but their useage became a lot rarer in the decades since. The Debug/Release mode covers most cases and for the rest you usually want adaptability at runtime rather then compile time. So you might never use #if.

Answer (score 2):

## `#if`

is a preprocessor directive . Preprocessor directives give instruction to the compiler to preprocess the information before actual compilation starts.
" #if " allows testing a symbol or symbols to see if they evaluate to true.

Eg.

```
#define PI 
using System;

namespace PreprocessorDAppl {
   class Program {
      static void Main(string[] args) {
         #if (PI)
            Console.WriteLine("PI is defined");
         #else
            Console.WriteLine("PI is not defined");
         #endif
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }
}
```

Above code will give the result : **PI is defined**

if is a conditional operator in c#. if statement will execute a block of code if the given condition is true.

```
if(num == 5){ 
  Console.WriteLine("Five")
}
```

Result : **Five**

Hope this helps